# Can't handle POST requests in node.js

Tags: node.js, http, post, get, http-headers

I have an assignment to write an `http` server in `node.js`, which is why I can't use the `http` module, as you'll soon see. Anyway, I need to be able to listen to both GET and POST requests. The way I understand it GET only fires `data` event, and post fires `data` and `end`. Here's my code:

```
function Server(resourceMap, rootFolder) {

    this.resourceMap = resourceMap;
    this.rootFolder = rootFolder;

    function connectionHandler(socket) {
        console.log('server connected');
        console.log('CONNECTED: ' + socket.remoteAddress +':'+ socket.remotePort);
        socket.setEncoding('utf8');
        socket.on('data',function(data) {
                var re = new RegExp("^( *)(GET)", "i");                 
                if (data.match(re) != null) {
                    console.log("Handling GET request");
                    router.route(data,socket,handle,resourceMap,rootFolder);
                }
                else {
                    (function() {
                        var postData = data;
                        socket.on('data',function(data) {
                            postData += data;
                        });
                        console.log(postData);
                        socket.on('end',function(postData) {
                            console.log("END");
                            console.log("Handling POST request");
                            router.route(postData,socket,handle,resourceMap,rootFolder);
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
    }

    this.server = net.createServer(connectionHandler);

    this.port = undefined;

    this.startServer = function(port) { //Maybe change backlog for security reasons
        this.port = port;
        this.server.listen(port, function() { //'listening' listener add handle object here
            console.log('server bound');});
    }
}
```

`GET` requests works just fine. With `POST` It doesn't even enter the anonymous function.

Any ideas why and how I can solve it?

EDIT: solved - I defined the function but didn't call it :)
If you have any comments about my design I'd love to hear, as I am new to node.js and JavaSCript

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Common mistake: **defined a function but did not call.**

You can either:

Get rid of the `function` keyword after else for regex

Or add `()` after function (which is more recomended)

Comment: It is a novice mistake, thanks. Other than that, if you have any comments about the design I'm interested to hear

Comment: @Yotam it looks ok, just nested to much so a bit hard to read (and debug for you). Its not a novice mistake, very often made